# Change text when button is clicked

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to change the text on a button ( `Start optimization` ) to ( `Cancel optimization` ) when the text was clicked. So far I got:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
                
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addLayout(self.optimize_button(), 1, 3, 1, 1)            
        
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)     
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)        


    # method for widgets
    def optimize_button(self):
        
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()  
        button = QPushButton("", self)
        button.setText("Start optimization")      
        button.setGeometry(200, 150, 100, 30)
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickme)    
        #self.push.clicked.connect(self.clickme)   
        hbox.addWidget(button)        
        self.show()        
        return hbox
  
    
    def clickme(self):
  
        print("pressed")
        self.button.setText("Cancel optimization")
```

I tried to make use out of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-how-to-change-the-text-of-existing-push-button/ but it doesn't work.
I guess the issue lays somewhere that clicking the button is calling `clickme()` which doesn't know anything about that button. But I don't know how to refer accordingly.

edit:

```
def clickme(self):

    print("pressed")
    self.button = QPushButton("", self)
    self.button.setText("Cancel optimization")
```

is not working?

Comment: Please construct a [mcve]. This code sample contains too much irrelevant information.

Comment: Some possible solutions: (1) store the button as a class member or (2) use [`QObject::sender`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#sender).

Comment: @m7913d Sorry, I removed the code I think is not necessary. I only wanted to avoid that there are some "cross-functional" issues within the code. Could you show me examples to your suggestions? I'm very new in pyqt.

Comment: `self.button = QPushButton(...)`. Also avoid unnecessary functions that you're just using once.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, unfortunately, I'm not quite sure where/how to use this. Within clickme() or within optimize_button() ?

Comment: You should ask yourself the following question: Should I add a new button inside `clickme`? Where is the button created that I want to edit? Store that button, so you can access it inside `clickme`. (Note that these questions are not specific to PyQt, but related to OOP or even programming in generic. So asking yourself those questions may be useful nevertheless the language you may use in the future.)

Comment: @m7913d I guess it's smarter to change an existing button via "clickme". This is what I am trying to do, without success, so far.

Comment: Your edit creates a new button (i.e. it calls the QPushButton constructor). You should store the one created in `optimize_button` (as you want to edit that button inside `clickme`)

Comment: I thought it would be somehow "stored" in the gridlayout? I'm confused with the term storing, here. I'm also new to pyqt what confuses actually everything a lot.

Comment: It is also stored in the gridlayout, accessing it from there is an option too, but rather cumbersome as you have to correctly locate it in the grid (which may change later on if you add extra items to your layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Store it as a class member

A solution is to:

- Store the button as a class member during construction
- Change the button that is stored as class member.

So, your simplified example would become:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
               
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()  
        self.button = QPushButton("", self) // (1) store the button as a class member
        button.setText("Start optimization")
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickme)    
        hbox.addWidget(button)        

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(hbox)     
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)        

        self.show()        
    
    def clickme(self):
  
        print("pressed")
        self.button.setText("Cancel optimization") // (2) self.button is the button stored in (1)
```

#### Option 2: [`QObject::sender`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#sender)

As mentioned in the comments, using `QObject::sender` may be an alternative to obtain the clicked button inside `clickme`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input!  I don't know how I would add the button to a specific grid position (refering to option 1).